# Laravel Mix import multiple globbed SCSS files into app.scss

Tags: css, laravel, webpack, sass, laravel-mix

I have a project structure where each component has its own SCSS file, and I would like to have all of these automatically imported into the project's main `app.scss` file, without having to list them all individually or update the list every time a new component is added. I know that merging a bunch of globbed CSS files could cause issues with selector order, but that is not a concern here.

I have tried this, with the `components.scss` file imported into `app.scss`:

```
mix.styles('resources/views/components/*.scss', 'resources/css/components.scss');
mix.sass('resources/css/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

And it basically works.

*Except*, `mix.styles()` runs after the Sass compilation, so you end up with the `components.scss` file from the previous execution being imported, rather than the current one.

Is there a way to solve this? Or is there another approach that would work?

As Sass `@import` does not support glob paths it's not possible to do something like this in `app.scss` as far as I am aware:

```
@import 'resources/views/components/*';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Discovered this can be done quite easily with [**node-sass-glob-importer**](https://github.com/maoberlehner/node-sass-magic-importer/tree/master/packages/node-sass-glob-importer), which is compatible with the Dart Sass implementation that Mix uses:

```
const sassGlobImporter = require('node-sass-glob-importer');

mix.sass('resources/css/app.scss', 'public/css', {
    sassOptions: {
        importer: sassGlobImporter(),
    }
});
```

`resources/css/app.scss`

```
@import '../views/components/**/*.scss';
```